# Optimize perl hash mess

Tags: perl, hash

I have Perl code, which looks messy:

```
         my $x = $h->[1];
         foreach my $y (keys %$x) {
           my $ax = $x->{$y};
           foreach my $ay (keys %$ax) {
             if (ref($ax->{$ay}) eq 'JE::Object::Proxy') {
               my $bx = $ax->{$ay};
               if ($$bx->{class_info}->{name} eq 'HTMLImageElement') {
                 print $$bx->{value}->{src}, "\n";
               }
             }
           }
         }
```

Is it possible to optimize the code above to not use any variables, just `$h`, as that one is an input?

Comment: Can you provide your sample input hash structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my crack at it:

```
print $$_->{value}{src}, "\n" for grep {
    ref $_ eq 'JE::Object::Proxy' &&
    $$_->{class_info}{name} eq 'HTMLImageElement'
} map {
    values %$_
} values %{ $h->[1] };
```

Answer (score 3):

A lot of the "messiness" can be cleaned up by reducing your line count and minimizing how much nested code you have. Use the `each` command to get the next key and its associated value from the hash in one line. [EDIT: as Axeman pointed out, you really only need the values, so I'm replacing my use of `each` with `values`]. Also, use a pair of `next` statement to skip the print statement.

```
for my $ax (values %{$h->[1]} ) {
    for my $bx (values %$ax ) {
        next unless ref($bx) eq 'JE::Object::Proxy';
        next unless $$bx->{class_info}->{name} eq 'HTMLImageElement';
        print "$$bx->{value}->{src}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 this is the only solution I can understand without staring at it for a while. Well done

Answer (score 3):

You're using keys, when you really just want `values`.

```
foreach my $h ( grep { ref() eq 'HASH' } values %$x ) { 
    foreach my $obj ( 
        grep {   ref()                  eq 'JE::Object::Proxy' 
             and $_->{class_info}{name} eq 'HTMLImageElement' 
             } values %$h 
        ) { 
        say $obj->{value}{src};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just removing the helper variables is easy, something like this should do it:

```
foreach my $y (keys %{$h->[1]}) {
  foreach my $ax (%{$h->[1]->{$y}) {
    foreach my $ay (keys %$ax) {
      if(ref($h->[1]->{$y}->{$ay}) eq 'JE::Object::Proxy') {
        if($h->[1]->{$y}->{$ay}->{class_info}->{name} eq 'HTMLImageElement') {
          print $h->[1]->{$y}->{$ay}->{value}->{src}, "\n";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could also remove the duplicated if:

```
foreach my $y (keys %{$h->[1]}) {
  foreach my $ax (%{$h->[1]->{$y}) {
    foreach my $ay (keys %$ax) {
      if(ref($h->[1]->{$y}->{$ay}) eq 'JE::Object::Proxy' && $h->[1]->{$y}->{$ay}->{class_info}->{name} eq 'HTMLImageElement') {
        print $h->[1]->{$y}->{$ay}->{value}->{src}, "\n";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I don't really see how to make it more readable: it is a iteration over a three dimensional structure.

Comment: A hint: code becomes almost always more readable by switching from procedural to declarative. [Data::DPath](http://p3rl.org/Data::DPath) dives into Perl data structures, similar like XPath does for XML.